# Faulty scroller fix via AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

How can I fix my mouse's faulty scroller using AHK? When I scroll down or up, it sometimes goes back a bit the opposite direction. I'm sure there's a way to deal with this in AHK but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WheelUp::
WheelDown::
SendInput, {%A_ThisHotkey%} ; remove this line if you don´t want the first tick to be registered 
; Impede scrolling in the opposite direction after the second tick:
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < DllCall("GetDoubleClickTime"))
    SendInput, {%A_ThisHotkey%}  ; or 
    ; SendInput, {%A_ThisHotkey% 2} ; if you want to scroll faster
return
```

**EDIT:**

Try also:

```
WheelUp::
If (A_PriorHotKey = WheelDown and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500) ; 500 ms, you can in- or decrease this time.
    SendInput, {WheelUp 2}
else
    SendInput, {WheelUp}
return

WheelDown::
If (A_PriorHotKey = WheelUp and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500)
    SendInput, {WheelDown 2}
else
    SendInput, {WheelDown}
return
```

Comment: Is there a way to "extend" the delay? It's still pushing through somewhat

Comment: Try my edited answer.

Comment: Up-voted this for the DllCall for GetDoubleClickTime... didn't know about that one... nice.

Comment: @user3419297 It still seems to push through even when I increased the delay to 5000ms (5 seconds)